# Quickfix/n, how to disable store and log factories?

Tags: c#, logging, quickfix, fix-protocol

How can I disable all of Quickfix/n's log and file factories? I want to handle all logging and message sending myself because I do not like the way how Quickfix sources log messages, meaning I want to decide when and how logging messages originate. Is there a way to completely disable any screen based or file based logging?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a NullLogFactory, but I don't currently see one, and I'm kind of confused why not.  I thought there was one.  (If you didn't know, I maintain QF/n.)

But you can create one like so:

```
public class NullLogFactory : ILogFactory
{
    SessionSettings settings_;

    #region LogFactory Members

    public NullLogFactory(SessionSettings settings)
    {}

    public ILog Create(SessionID sessionID)
    {
        return new QuickFix.NullLog();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The next QF/n release will contain a null factory or something to fill that gap.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but possibly of use to somebody that searches for this.

If you want to make it easier to enable/disable logging I think it is much better to set a value in the app.config file and process it in the socket initiator class as such:

**App.config**

```
   <appSettings>
    <add key="LogMessages" value="false"/>
   </appSettings>
```

**Application Code**

```
bool logMessages = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogMessages"]);


try
{
    SocketInitiator initiator;
    QuickFix.SessionSettings settings = new QuickFix.SessionSettings(file);
    MessageProcessor application = new MessageProcessor();
    QuickFix.IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory = new QuickFix.FileStoreFactory(settings);
    QuickFix.ILogFactory logFactory = new QuickFix.FileLogFactory(settings);

    if (!logMessages)
        {
            initiator = new QuickFix.Transport.SocketInitiator(application, storeFactory, settings);
        }
        else
        {
            initiator = new QuickFix.Transport.SocketInitiator(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory);
        }


    application.MyInitiator = initiator;

    initiator.Start();
    while (!initiator.IsLoggedOn)
    {
        //wait until the initiator has logged on
    }
    //do stuff
}
catch
{// exception handling code}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is an old one but hope this answer will help if anyone have the same issue as I did not find any related question.

According to the [Quickfix Configuration](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/configuration.html#logging), default value of `FileLogPath` in your configuration file is '-'. Therefore, remove or comment the `FileLogPath` setting from your configuration file.

When you create the socket initiator instance, you have 3 overloads by Quickfix SocketInitiator class as mentioned bellow.

```
public SocketInitiator(IApplication application, IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory, SessionSettings settings);
public SocketInitiator(IApplication application, IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory, SessionSettings settings, ILogFactory logFactory);
public SocketInitiator(IApplication application, IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory, SessionSettings settings, ILogFactory logFactory, IMessageFactory messageFactory);
```

We need to use the first one as we need to switch off the quickfix logs.

Sample code segment is mentioned bellow

```
SessionSettings settings = new("your-config.cfg");
IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
SocketInitiator initiator = new(_application, storeFactory, settings);
```

Afterwith, you can implement different logging mechanism to handle your logs. For example, *Serilog*

Comment: please, how to avoid MessageStoreFactory while  creating the socket initiator instance. i don't want to store anything ?